# What causes this weird text outline in all my browsers in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, fonts

After reinstalling Windows 8.1 I noticed that there are some text outlines in all browsers (I tried IE and Chrome):
[image]

What might cause this problem? I checked the settings in both Windows and Chrome but I did not find any settings regarding text outlines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating your video card drivers. Since you did a clean install it may be using a generic driver, which can cause odd display problems on certain video cards.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that it has nothing to do with the video card since other fonts are OK. This should be a comment.